# Creating a for loop for summing columns values in a data frame

Tags: r

I'm new to r so I'm having a hard time figuring this out. I have a data frame and I want to create a vector with a **for** loop called like *"SumQuadCol"*, where SumQuadCol[j] = the square of the values contained in a column if the column class is numeric, and SumQuadCol[j] = NA if the class is not numeric.

I tried something like this:

```
for (j in 1: ncol(dat)){
  if (is.numeric(ncol(dat[j]))){
    SumQuadCol <- (colSums(is.numeric(dat[j]))) ^2
  }else {
    (SumQuadCol = NA)}
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: `is.numeric` gives you logical TRUE/FALSE values, then we are summing them, then squaring them? Review your steps. Provide example input data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a vector to store the result, use `dat[[j]]` to get access to the values of the column. Using `iris` dataset -

```
dat <- iris

SumQuadCol <- numeric(length(dat))

for (j in seq_along(dat)) {
  if (is.numeric(dat[[j]])) {
    SumQuadCol[j] <- sum(dat[[j]]^2)
  }else {
    SumQuadCol[j] = NA
  }
}

SumQuadCol
#[1] 5223.85 1430.40 2582.71  302.33      NA
```

You can also use `sapply` -

```
sapply(dat, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) sum(x^2) else NA)

#Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
#     5223.85      1430.40      2582.71       302.33           NA
```

Comment: I tried this for cycle you wrote and it returns everything as NA values

Comment: There might be `NA` values in your data. Try using `sum(dat[[j]]^2, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: You're right, now it works! Thank you so much!